# Replacing Dot to comma in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have an issue when I try to replace all "." with ","
It works normal when I use Ctrl + H in the Excel Sheet and do it manually.

I have recorded the Macro from what I do in the sheet, and got this code

```
Columns("Q:S").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But when I run the Macro it only removes the "." , instead of replacing it with "," .

So for instance, if the cell states 4.000 aftter I run the Macro, it returns 4000.
How do I fix this??

I have also tried changing decimal separators in the system, but it does not help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the format of the cells before and after you run the macro?

Comment: Depends on your format and your language's decimal/thousand seperators. It technically *did* change the "." in ","

Comment: Are the cells numbers or text that looks like numbers?

Comment: What do you *want* 4.000 to become - 4 or 4 thousand? If the former, replace the dot with a dot, since VBA operates as if in a US locale.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* replace all the periods with commas regardless of data type. (as a string, so you'll no longer be able to easily calculate from them)

You'll **still** be running into **a lot** of trouble if you want these numbers to be numbers, with correct separators.
As a side note, When I used find and replace (Ctrl + H) I got the same result where my "4.123" became "4,123.00". This may be related to our system settings.

```
Sub Test_Replace_Period_with_Comma()

    Dim ValueRange As Range
    Dim ValueSet
    
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    
    Set ValueRange = Intersect(Columns("Q:S"), Sheet8.UsedRange)
    ValueSet = ValueRange
    
    If ValueRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim ValueSet(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    End If
    
    For X = 1 To UBound(ValueSet, 1)
        For Y = 1 To UBound(ValueSet, 2)
            'Debug.Print ValueSet(X, Y)
            If ValueSet(X, Y) <> "" Then
                ValueSet(X, Y) = Replace(CStr(ValueSet(X, Y)), ".", ",", 1, , vbTextCompare)
            End If
        Next Y
    Next X
    
    ValueRange.NumberFormat = "@"
    ValueRange = ValueSet
    
End Sub
```

[image] [image]